# In overleaf export a bib-file with only cited references (using narbig, on Mac if important)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, overleaf

While there are already many options available when you run LaTeX on your local machine, is there a way to also use one of these options when using Overleaf?

Comment: If you want to do this fully online within Overleaf then the answer is probably "no". However, some of the tools for local systems can be used stand-alone without LaTeX itself being installed, so it might work to download the relevant files (`.bib`, `.aux`, `.tex`) to your local system and then run such a tool. It would help if you can provide a list of the "many options available" that you have found so far, that makes it easier to suggest for each of them if it can be used stand-alone or not.

Comment: Thank you, I will link them